# MEDIA_URL in class-based view

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, media-url

I'm not able to access `MEDIA_URL` in my class-based view.

My understanding has been that I would create my view, and my context processor would provide it into my function-based view.  Now I'm trying to switch to class-based, and I no longer have access to `MEDIA_URL`.

Do context processors not work with class-based views?  Do I have to add it to my context manually now?

Here are my processors:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)
```

My previous views looked something like:

```
def my_view(request):
    context = {
        "foo": "bar"
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

And I would be able to use `{{MEDIA_URL}}`.

My class-based view looks like:

```
class MyView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        context = {
            "foo": "bar"
        }
        return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

And I cannot access `{{MEDIA_URL}}`

Comment: What version of Django are you using? Django 1.8 moved the configuration of `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` to the `TEMPLATES` setting. Beyond that I don't think you shouldn't need to access `MEDIA_URL` in the template. It's a bad code smell to me. You should be using the url generated from the file storage api (i.e. `{{ model.field.url }}`).

Comment: I had just started using 1.8 from 1.7 and didn't realize that they had made that change.  That fixed my issue.

Also, I didn't realize I was able to access media that way, I just switched to it and it worked perfectly, thanks for the tip.  I'm having to pick up Django/Python as I go and reading the docs along the way.  

If you can post your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django 1.8 moved the configuration of `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` to the `TEMPLATES` setting. Beyond that I don't think you shouldn't need to access `MEDIA_URL` in the template. It's a bad code smell to me. You should be using the url generated from the file storage api (i.e. `{{ model.field.url }}`).